# Fetch data when you have multiple search queries in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, database, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have this type of modal for search data from the database.

**Image**

[image]

I want to search the data if the user only types **company name and CIN** or  **company name only* or
**company state and company district** user can choose any field. So I want to fetch the data only on selected fields.

Is there any simplest way to do this

I have coded multiple **if-else statements**.

**My Code**

```
 else if ($req->state && $req->district) {
            $data = tbl_company::query()
                ->where(
                    "state",
                    "LIKE",
                    "%{$req->state}%"
                )->where(
                    "district",
                    "LIKE",
                    "%{$req->district}%"
                )
                ->paginate(100);
        }

        // Filter using only state and city

        else if ($req->city && $req->district && $req->state == null) {
            $data = tbl_company::query()
                ->where(
                    "city",
                    "LIKE",
                    "%{$req->city}%"
                )->where(
                    "district",
                    "LIKE",
                    "%{$req->district}%"
                )
                ->paginate(100);
        }

        // company status only
        else if ($req->company_status && $req->city == null && $req->district == null && $req->state == null) {
            $data = tbl_company::query()
                ->where(
                    "company_status",
                    $req->company_status
                )
                ->paginate(100);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [Conditional Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#conditional-clauses)

```
$data = tbl_company::query()->when($req->state && $req->district, function ($query, $req) {
        $query->where("state", "LIKE", "%{$req->state}%")
            ->where("district", "LIKE", "%{$req->district}%");
    })->when($req->city && $req->district && $req->state == null, function ($query, $req) {

        $query->where("city", "LIKE", "%{$req->city}%")
            ->where("district", "LIKE", "%{$req->district}%");
    })->paginate(100);
```

**Updates**
use loop

```
$data = tbl_company::query()->where(function ($query)use($req){
    foreach ($req->only('state','district','city','company_status') as $filterField=>$filterFieldValue){
        if(!empty($filterFieldValue)&&is_array($filterFieldValue)){
            $query->wherein($filterField,$filterFieldValue);
        }elseif (!empty($filterFieldValue)){
            $query->where($filterField, "LIKE", "%{$filterFieldValue}%");
        }
    }
})->paginate(100);
```

Comment: can't we do this on one condition? coz conditional clauses and my code basically the same.

Comment: Okay, sir. but I tried but got `array to string conversion error`. Actually, I am sending multiple values from the front side.

Comment: @swapnilmane try to print and debug so you can find for which it throws errors.my solution purely based on mentioned code from the question

Comment: I have updated the image sir.

Comment: @swapnilmane updated the answer.you might need to change accordingly based on errros.

Comment: Sir your answer works like a charm. Super Awesome ! but there is a one problem. I have dates as well. I want to filter data between date ranges as well how I can implement this with your code.

Comment: @swapnilmane you have to use another condition if you want to filter date based on filed name

Comment: Okay Sir but I have `$req->start_date_of_registration` and `$req->end_date_of_registration` from request and I have named a column with only `date_of_registration` and it shows the unknown column error. can you please update your answer

Comment: I have added if condition but it is returning all the data.

Comment: @swapnilmane try to debug code line by line so you can find solution and for unknown column it might be start_date_of_registration  or end_date_of_registration  columns doesn't exist in database table. so if you are using different column in frontend then change and maintain same column as database table column

Comment: Okay sir. I have updated the code. You will find bottom of the question. I have used my previous code and embedded into that coz i have string data type column for date in my database.

Comment: Sir, if i change the column name from the front end then how can I get two dates from the front end. I will get only one date from the request.

Comment: @swapnilmane better ask new question with more detail so some one can help you.

Comment: I have asked sir. If you do know how to do this . here you can answer it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73350259/filter-data-between-dates-along-with-multiple-search-queries-in-laravel

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. I solved this problem using **Pipeline Design Pattern**

```
 $query = tbl_company::query();

        if ($req->has('state')) {
            $query->whereIn('state', $req->input('state'));
        }

        if ($req->has('district')) {
            $query->whereIn('district', $req->input('district'));
        }
        if ($req['date_of_registration']['start'] && $req['date_of_registration']['end']) {
            $from = Carbon::parse($req['date_of_registration']['start']);
            $to = Carbon::parse($req['date_of_registration']['end']);
            $query->whereBetween(
                DB::Raw("STR_TO_DATE(date_of_registration,'%d-%m-%Y')"),
                [$from, $to]
            );
        }
        if ($req['authorized_capital']['start'] && $req['authorized_capital']['end']) {
            $query->whereBetween(
                "authorized_capital",
                [$req['authorized_capital']['start'], $req['authorized_capital']['end']]
            );
        }

//finally
$data = $query->paginate(100);
```