# filter data between dates along with multiple search queries in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, database, eloquent

I want to filter the data between dates. I have so many columns from the front end.

**Screenshot of front end columns**
[image]

I have the following code that works fine unless the date filter comes.
How can I add the date filter in this code and that will work.

I have provided the blade file code and the controller's function code below.

** BLADE FILE**

```
<form action="/filter/companies/data" method="get" >
            <h5 class="text-center">Basic Filters</h5>
            <input type="text" name="company_name" id="" placeholder="Company Name" class="form-control">
            <input type="text" name="cin" id="" placeholder="CIN" class="form-control my-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Company Status</label>
                <select class="select2 select2-hidden-accessible" multiple="" data-placeholder="Company Status" style="width: 100%;"  tabindex="-1" name="company_status[]" aria-hidden="true">
                    <option value="Active">Active</option>
                    <option value="Inactive ">Inactive </option>
                </select>
                </div> 
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Company Category</label>
                <select class="select2 select2-hidden-accessible" multiple="" data-placeholder="Company Category" style="width: 100%;"  tabindex="-1" name="company_category[]" aria-hidden="true">
                    @foreach($company_category2 as $key => $item)
                    <option value="{{$item}}">{{$item}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
                </div> 
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">Activity Code</label>
                    <select class="select2 select2-hidden-accessible" multiple="" data-placeholder="Activity Code" style="width: 100%;"  tabindex="-1" name="activity_code[]" aria-hidden="true">
                        @foreach($activity_code2 as $key => $item)
                        <option value="{{$item}}">{{$item}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                    </div> 
            <input type="text" name="roc" id="" placeholder="ROC" class="form-control my-2">
                <hr/>
            <h5 class="text-center">Company Details</h5>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Company Class</label>
                <select class="select2 select2-hidden-accessible" multiple="" data-placeholder="Company Class" style="width: 100%;"  tabindex="-1" name="company_class[]" aria-hidden="true">
                    <option value="Public Company">Public Company</option>
                    <option value="Private Company">Private Company</option>
                </select>
                </div> 
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">Company Type</label>
                    <select class="select2 select2-hidden-accessible" multiple="" data-placeholder="Company Type" style="width: 100%;"   name="company_type[]" aria-hidden="true">
                        @foreach($company_type2 as $key => $item)
                        <option value="{{$item}}">{{$item}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                    </div> 
            <input type="text" name="office_type" id="" placeholder="Office Type" class="form-control my-2">
            <input type="text" name="llpin" id="" placeholder="LLP IN" class="form-control my-2">
            <input type="text" name="llp_name" id="" placeholder="LLP NAME" class="form-control my-2">
            <input type="text" name="industrial_activity" id="" placeholder="Industrial Activity" class="form-control my-2">
           <hr/>
            <h5 class="text-center">Filter using Contact Details</h5>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="" placeholder="Email" class="form-control mb-2">
            <input type="text" name="mobile_number" id="" placeholder="Mobile Number" class="form-control my-2">
            <hr/>
            <h5 class="text-center">Filter using Authorized Capital</h5>
            <input type="text" name="from_authorized_capital" id="" placeholder="From Authorized Capital" class="form-control mb-2">
            <input type="text" name="to_authorized_capital" id="" placeholder="To Authorized Capital" class="form-control my-2">
            <hr/>
            <h5 class="text-center">Filter using Locations</h5>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Select State</label>
                <select class="select2 select2-hidden-accessible" multiple="" data-placeholder="Select a State" style="width: 100%;"  tabindex="-1" name="state[]" aria-hidden="true">
                    @foreach($states as $key => $item)
                    <option value="{{$item}}">{{$item}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
                </div> 

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">Select District</label>
                    <select class="select2 select2-hidden-accessible" multiple="" data-placeholder="Select a District" style="width: 100%;"  tabindex="-1" name="district[]" aria-hidden="true">
                        @foreach($districts as $key => $item)
                        <option value="{{$item}}">{{$item}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                    </div> 
            <input type="text" name="city" id="" placeholder="City" class="form-control my-2">
            
            <hr/>
            <h5 class="text-center">Dates Of Registration</h5>
            <label for="">Start Date</label>
                            <input type="date" name="date_of_registration[start]" id=""  class="form-control my-2 mb-2">
            <label for="">End Date</label>
                           <input type="date" name="date_of_registration[end]" id=""  class="form-control my-2 mb-2">
            <hr/>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success my-2">Filter</button>
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-secondary my-2">Reset</button>
        </form>
```

**CONTROLLER FUNCTION**

```
 $data = tbl_company::query()->where(function ($query) use ($req) {
            foreach ($req->only('state', 'district', 'city', 'company_status', 'activity_code', 'company_category', 'company_class', 'company_type', 'office_type', 'date_of_registration') as $filterField => $filterFieldValue) {
                if ($req['date_of_registration']['start'] && $req['date_of_registration']['end']) {
                    $from = Carbon::parse($req['date_of_registration']['start']);
                    $to = Carbon::parse($req['date_of_registration']['end']);
                    $query->whereBetween(
                        DB::Raw("STR_TO_DATE(date_of_registration,'%d-%m-%Y')"),
                        [$from, $to]
                    );
                } elseif (!empty($filterFieldValue) && is_array($filterFieldValue)) {
                    $query->wherein($filterField, $filterFieldValue);
                } elseif (!empty($filterFieldValue)) {
                    $query->where($filterField, "LIKE", "%{$filterFieldValue}%");
                }
            }
        })->paginate(100);
```

Comment: better include blade file so it will be more clarity

Comment: I have added blade file code sir.

Comment: .what is the field name in database table for date registration

Comment: `date_of_registration`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I solved this problem using **Pipeline Design Pattern**

```
 $query = tbl_company::query();

        if ($req->has('state')) {
            $query->whereIn('state', $req->input('state'));
        }

        if ($req->has('district')) {
            $query->whereIn('district', $req->input('district'));
        }
        if ($req['date_of_registration']['start'] && $req['date_of_registration']['end']) {
            $from = Carbon::parse($req['date_of_registration']['start']);
            $to = Carbon::parse($req['date_of_registration']['end']);
            $query->whereBetween(
                DB::Raw("STR_TO_DATE(date_of_registration,'%d-%m-%Y')"),
                [$from, $to]
            );
        }
        if ($req['authorized_capital']['start'] && $req['authorized_capital']['end']) {
            $query->whereBetween(
                "authorized_capital",
                [$req['authorized_capital']['start'], $req['authorized_capital']['end']]
            );
        }

// filtered data.
$data = $query->paginate(100);
```